# Can I get Ubuntu One to automatically download and sync a folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I would like to know if it's possible to automatically download to local a folder in Ubuntu One every time that I have internet connection.

Comment: This is roughly how Ubuntu One is supposed to work. If Ubuntu One is installed correctly, you should be able to select `File > Ubuntu One > Synchronize this folder` to sync a local folder to Ubuntu One, or store everything in your Ubuntu One folder. Is that not working? Or can you say a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Just put all the files you want to have synchronised in the Ubuntu One folder in your home folder.

The folder synchronise across all devices/laptops/desktops that are logged into Ubuntu One. Just don't switch between devices too quickly. Syncing takes time.